# Android studio refactoring fail (read-only)

Tags: android, android-studio

I cannot refactor (rename) anything in my layouts, I already tried rebuilding and cleaning the project and many solutions i found, but none worked. 
I can do it directly in file system, or manually in Studio (so I also have to find and change every line where it is used but it is slow and dangerous process)
AS 3.0 beta 3, Debian 9
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Fq2.png

Comment: try using `chmod` command on these directories or try to run Android studio as Admin!

Comment: @AtefHares 
chmod 755 /directory_path/ -R also not working

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Beta 3 was "recalled" due to a bug they found after the release. [Check this for reference](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-3-is-now.html). You should revert to Android Studio 3 beta 2 and it may fix the problem. Beta 2 can be downloaded from the Android Studio website.
The bug itself appears to be affecting both Beta 3 and 4. There isn't much to do about it, and reverting to beta 2 still looks like the best option as of now. Beta 5 may fix it, but there is no way of knowing.

---

The bug has since been fixed in beta 5, according to the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65032914#comment19).

Comment: @vigilancer everyone screws up in software, and when we install beta versions we know there is a risk there is a bug even Google missed. If you don't want to live with bugs like that, don't install beta versions

Comment: yeah, well, I can understand when it's about rarely used features. but refactoring for gods sake, it's essential. and it's still broken in Beta 4. anyway, that's the world we live in and all that.

Comment: It's not easy 'not use it', I'm already adopting some new breaking changes, like gradle plugin version bump, `matchingFallbacks`. It will take some efforts to rollback to stable.  I'm just saying google's definition of `beta` feels more like alpha. I didn't expect that, now I know, so only releases for me please. I understand risks of beta versions, but that can't stop me from bitching about it.

Comment: I only recently started jumping on the beta train because I really needed some of the new features (most notably Java 8 without jack, it screws up my entire build for whatever reason). You are allowed to complain about it (never said you weren't). They screwed up in beta 4 too, same error (with the exception that beta 4 doesn't have a Gradle-destroying bug). You shouldn't stop checking preview versions just because of this, but make some "rules". I only use beta if there are some extremely important upgrades, and I only update the preview if I know the version is stable enough for me to dev in

Comment: @Aracem add a link actually validating that statement. Rolled back the edit until you do

Comment: The bug is already fixed in Beta 5 that it's already released :)
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65032914#comment19

Answer (score 7):

[image]this can be solved go to: on the righ corner find gradle ---> :app ---> other ---> clean 
after successful cleaning
dont rebuild the project yet
after cleaning do a refactor rename
start your app again.

Comment: To my surprise the workaround actually works in Android Studio beta 4.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a bug in Android Studio 3.0 Beta 3, which describes exactly your behaviour:

[Can't rename resource (layout) files in Android Studio 3.0 Beta 3](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65079508)

Answer (score 1):

As we knows it is the bug in Android Studio 3.0-beta 4

Please try the following for work around

1. Download Android Studio 3.0-beta 2
2. Manually Clean the Project and rebuild **everytime** when you have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it:

Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart