# Android studio 3 beta 4. Refactoring cannot be performed

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring, android-studio-3.0

I have a problem with the latest beta update trying to refactor the view or xml layout name id in xml.
The error dialog says

> Refactoring cannot be performed File
>   C:\dev\workspace......\R.java is read-only.

Things I've tried:
Gradle clean, Invalidate cache/restart. None helped. I also tested with strings and other resources. The same problem happens there.

The problem appeared in the beta 4 update. In beta 2 refactoring worked fine.

Comment: yes it is a reported bug. revert back to previous version.

Comment: @AtefHares [beta 3](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html) doesn't exist. They removed [because of issues with Gradle](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-3-is-now.html) . If you see the first link with a list of the releases, beta 3 isn't listed. And beta 3 is **extremely bugged**, avoid it if you somehow can get your hands on it. Revert to Beta 2 instead if you decide to revert

Comment: @LunarWatcher Yes you are correct. Sorry, I just forgot about this!

Comment: @LunarWatcher, i am on beta 4, not 3. I updated through the android studio itself

Comment: AtefHares suggested you revert back to beta 3 from beta 4. I know beta 4 is released, but reverting back to beta 3 is a horrible idea. I explained **why** reverting back to beta3 shouldn't be the solution. If you are going to revert, revert to beta 2, not 3. I know you run 4. If you want to solve it instead of reverting, I urge you to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45879726/6296561) - I'm not marking as a dupe because that post is about beta 3. With beta 3 being extremely bugged, the beta 4 could have a different cause.

Comment: @LunarWatcher is it possible to download the beta 2 version now? The preview site has only latest build available for download.
edit: found it here https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Comment: Well I can't refactor my strings in the xml file... canary 6 fix this problem?

Comment: getting same problem on beta 4

Comment: Another user found a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064561/8575353

Comment: @ajora cleaning is not solution because you loose generated R.java, and as the result, can not access resources from code. Only solution there still reverting back to Beta 2.

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio Beta 5 has solved this problem.

Comment: Indeed. Do you know if there's any way to make the "set current layout as default" actually work? I'm on a mac and I can't get it to work properly. It seems like it's setting the proper settings in the window.manager file in the preferences folder, but when I click restore default layout (or just navigate away from and back to a layout file) my component tree window and palette windows both start floating and get really small.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue on Android Studio 3.0 Beta 5 and 6.
If your  R.java file is read-only and your package name is com.example.sample just remove the file app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com/example/sample/R.java (R.java,Manifest.java...), then try again when you're finished refactoring, it will be regenerated during the build process.